# REST API compare current user if exist in a custom list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery

I have a custom list with 37 user fields, I need to check if the current user is in one of those fields to display an alert.

I'm getting the current user with this url:

```
/_api/web/currentUser
```

And then I'm checking the user id against the ids in the custom list by doing 37 filters

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Global Contact List')/items?$filter=((field1 eq '"+ userId +"') or (field2 eq '"+ userId +"') ...
```

But apparently I'm not allowed to make more than 35 filters.

Can someone help me achieve this approach?

Thanks

Comment: You need to get whole list item and then check current user in each list item field manually..!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GET request has maximum length limit configured in the `web.config`. It is 260 characters I guess. So it is the reason you can not make more than 35 filters.

So now you can consider **POST** and **CAML**. Make a **CAML** Query like following. `field1` and `field2` are considered in the following query. Do not forget to include others.

```
var query = "<View> " + 
 "  <Query> " + 
 "    <Where> " + 
 "      <Or> " + 
 "        <Eq> " + 
 "          <FieldRef Name=\"field1\" /> " + 
 "          <Value Type=\"Integer\"> " + 
 "            <UserID Type=\"Integer\" /> " + 
 "          </Value> " + 
 "        </Eq> " + 
 "        <Eq> " + 
 "          <FieldRef Name=\"field2\" /> " + 
 "          <Value Type=\"Integer\"> " + 
 "            <UserID Type=\"Integer\" /> " + 
 "          </Value> " + 
 "        </Eq> " + 
 "      </Or> " + 
 "    </Where> " + 
 "  </Query> " + 
 "</View> "
```

**Request Body**

```
var data = {
    query: {
        __metadata: {
            'type': 'SP.CamlQuery'
        },
        ViewXml: query
    }
};
```

Now make a **POST** request to the following URL. I hope it will serve your purpose.

```
"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Global Contact List')/getitems";
```

Following things may help you to build **CAML**

1. [U2U Caml Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Software)
2. [Building CAML for querying List in SharePoint](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993035/Building-CAML-for-querying-List-in-SharePoint)

Comment: Technically inaccurate, GET has no specified limit, if a server cant handle the length of a request it must respond with 414 URI Too Long