# How get multiples users by id with REST API?

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, user-profile-property, api

I need get multiple users by ID with REST API. I looked this question: [How to get multiple users with REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/168028/how-to-get-multiple-users-with-rest-api)

But is not answered.

I've the ID's in an array:

```
var people = [426, 352, 155];
```

I've already seen this way:

```
http://siteurl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList(426)
```

But I want get all users info in only one request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For few items in ID's array, then you can try following

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('User Information List')/Items?$filter=(Id eq 426) or (Id eq 352) or (Id eq 155)
```

It will give you all users in one request. Remember GET request has MAX URL length.

For many items in ID's array, you have to use CAML & POST. CAML Should look like

```
<Where>
    <In>
        <FieldRef Name="ID" />
        <Values>
            <Value Type="Integer">426</Value>
            <Value Type="Integer">352</Value>
            <Value Type="Integer">155</Value>
            .............
        </Values>
    </In>
</Where>
```

End-Point will be

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('User Information List')/getitems
```

Also see my another [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/165905/21421) about MAX URL length for GET request.

Comment: I've the error: `The List 'User Information List' does not exist on the site with the URL` :/

Comment: My sharepoint is in Portuguese, the list is named  "Lista de Informações sobre o Usuário"

Comment: So change the list name and try

Comment: Yes, I'm testing.